# Web application deployment approach using Google Cloud - GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I deploying a python + tensorflow + flask application using a fully managed Google Cloud Run Service (1 vCPUs and 4 GB Ram).

System works fine but it is really slow, so I am evaluating ways of making it fast (it needs to run 20-30 times faster than what is doing now)

What would be the best approach?

- To use a Kubernetes Cluster with one or two powerful machines
- To use a Kubernetes Cluster with 3-5 weaker machines
- To forget about Kubernets/Docker and run everything on single powerfull VM
- Something else maybe?

For now I don't expect to have more than 10 users at a time but I want to be able to scale it up eventually.

Comment: Kubernetes has nothing to do with a performance of application. You dont even mention what kind of workload is it doing, so it's impossible to give any advice. Can you app distribute the workload among multiple machines? If no, why do you think clustering the app would help? If yes, then it's a bit pointless to ask the question, since it's the easiest way to go, if you can throw resources at it.

Comment: Thanks for the friendly reply @yedpodtrzitko. If I knew what I was doing I would not be reaching out for help. Answering your questions: (1) workload is CPU intensive (2) I will need to update the app so it can work with multiple machines (3) I am not sure what it is easier/cheaper to develop, hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to evaluate according to your use case

[Per this article,](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/when-to-use-google-kubernetes-engine-vs-cloud-run-for-containers) Fully managed Cloud Run is an ideal serverless platform for stateless containerized microservices that don’t require Kubernetes features like namespaces, co-location of containers in pods (sidecars) or node allocation and management.

GKE is a great choice if you are looking for a container orchestration platform that offers advanced scalability and configuration flexibility.

You mentioned you are looking the cheaper/easier method to develop, but this will probably not be as scalable, efficient or manageable, you might want to take a closer look at all [cloud compute options](https://cloud.google.com/hosting-options) in GCP to see what could benefit your use case the most.

You mentioned your use case is CPU intensive, so you might want to leverage the [high CPU machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#highcpu), these might be used directly by creating a VM, creating an [instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups) or using them in other services like [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture#memory_cpu) or [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes)